# How to modify the onOptionClick function of a multiselect list from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with JQuery-multiselect. I created a multiselect list that works fine.
I need to modify it so that the user cannot select more than 3 options in the list.
I can't find the syntax to do this so I kindly ask for your help.

Here I initalize my list:

```
jquery_objet_types_multiselect = jQuery('#id_...').multiselect({
            columns: 1,
            placeholder: 'Sélection ...',
            search: true,
            selectAll: true
        });
```

And here is the part that I can't do yet:

```
jquery_objet_types_multiselect.multiselect('onOptionClick', function( element, option ) {
                if( $(element).val().length > maxSelectTypeFlux ) {
                    if( $(option).is(':checked') ) {
                        var thisVals = $(element).val();

                        thisVals.splice(
                            thisVals.indexOf( $(option).val() ), 1
                        );

                        $(element).val( thisVals );

                        $(option).prop( 'checked', false ).closest('li')
                            .toggleClass('selected');
                    }
                }
                else if( $(element).val().length == maxSelectTypeFlux ) {
                    $(element).next('.ms-options-wrap')
                        .find('li:not(.selected)').addClass('disabled')
                        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
                            .attr( 'disabled', 'disabled' );
                }
                else {
                    $(element).next('.ms-options-wrap')
                        .find('li.disabled').removeClass('disabled')
                        .find('input[type="checkbox"]')
                            .removeAttr( 'disabled' );
                }
            });
```

I declared jquery_objet_types_multiselect and maxSelectTypeFlux in the beginning.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Putting something along these lines (will probably have to be tweaked to work in your case) at the top of your function might work. The idea is to check if there are 3 options selected already (my logic might be a bit off here its early on a friday morning lol) and if theres 3 options already selected you want to not allow the user to add another option and exit the function.

```
if ($('option').length == 3) {
    $(element).preventDefault()
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually my issue is not with the maximum selection but rather with how to switch from the original onOptionClick function to my function, using Jquery-multiselect. The idea is to allow the multiselection only when I want